# How to hide cursor in a Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, mouse-cursor

Is there a way to hide cursor (other than using transparent image as a cursor)?

I want to hide the cursor, when the user point the mouse outside JPanel in JFrame.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It appears that the [`Cursor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html) class does not have a "blank" cursor to begin with, so one could define a new "blank" cursor using the [`Toolkit.createCustomCursor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor(java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.lang.String)) method.

Here's one way I've tried which seems to work:

```
// Transparent 16 x 16 pixel cursor image.
BufferedImage cursorImg = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

// Create a new blank cursor.
Cursor blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
    cursorImg, new Point(0, 0), "blank cursor");

// Set the blank cursor to the JFrame.
mainJFrame.getContentPane().setCursor(blankCursor);
```

---

**Edit**

Regarding the comment about everything inside the `JFrame` ending up without a cursor, it seems that the `Component`s which are contained in the `JFrame` will end up inheriting the cursor of the container (the `JFrame`), so if it is a requirement to have a certain `Component` have the cursor appear, one would have to manually set the desired cursor.

For example, if there is a `JPanel` contained in the `JFrame`, then one could set the cursor of that `JPanel` to the system's default using the [`Cursor.getDefaultCursor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html#getDefaultCursor()) method:

```
JPanel p = ...
// Sets the JPanel's cursor to the system default.
p.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Coobird. But I have another problem. I created JFrame which contains JPanel, which size is smaller than the JFrame. I only want the cursor disappears when the mouse pointed outside the JPanel.Is that means that when I set the cursor in the main JFrame as invisible, the cursor will disappear completely on the screen?

Comment: Hi Jessy, I've added the part about how to set the JPanel to the system default in my answer.

Comment: hi, I am trying to draw mouse cursor in paint method ...but i am getting Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: invalid hotSpot ?

any one have about this is happening?

Answer (score 10):

*tl;dr* AWT Toolkits are still bugged in 2017'; the proper solution is thus to call

```
  w.setCursor( w.getToolkit().createCustomCursor(
                   new BufferedImage( 1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB ),
                   new Point(),
                   null ) );
```

instead.

---

As per [Javadoc page for `createCustomCursor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor(java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.lang.String)),

> Creates a new custom cursor object.
> If the image to display is invalid, the cursor will be hidden (made
> completely transparent), and the hotspot will be set to (0, 0).

It would follow from that that

```
w.setCursor( w.getToolkit().createCustomCursor( null, null, null ) );
```

should do the trick. Sadly, there is a bug related to this case NOT handled by the code, see e.g. https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7150089 (this particular is for MacOS, but by browsing the source you may easily find that there's no checking for 1st param `Image` value validity in *any* of the `Toolkit` platform implementations; there's `tracker.isErrorAny()` checking, which doesn't do it's job in this case), so passing `null` or invalid `Image` simply throws a NPEx.

Answer (score 3):

When using the LWJGL under Mac OS you need to do this:

```
System.setProperty("apple.awt.fullscreenhidecursor","true");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
frame.setCursor(frame.getToolkit().createCustomCursor(
            new BufferedImage(3, 3, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB), new Point(0, 0),
            "null"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation it says that if the image is invalid, then it will be transparent by default so therefore passing an empty image will result in a transparent cursor. But Passing `null` into the method for the image will result in an exception.

```
Toolkit tk= getToolkit();
Cursor transparent = tk.createCustomCursor(tk.getImage(""), new Point(), "trans");
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem much easier:

```
final Timer cursorTimer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        getContentPane().setCursor(null);
    }
});
cursorTimer.start();

addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        getGlassPane().setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        cursorTimer.restart();
    }
});
```