# java lwjgl how to make the mouse invisible

Tags: java, mouse, lwjgl

I am making a 3D game and I have just got the ability to allow the mouse to move the camera and then put the mouse back to the centre. But I want don't want the user to see an annoying mouse at the centre of the screen! So what I'm asking is: how do I make the mouse invisible? / how do I make the cursor disappear?
I thought that there would be a `Mouse.setVisible(false);` but doesn't seem to exist. Thanks in advance. Also I want to do it without making a blank image. *I'm using LWJGL 2 for java*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984071/how-to-hide-cursor-in-a-swing-application Last suggestion or Cursor method should work as well. I don't know if you are using any sort of JFrames for this so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Mouse.setGrabbed(true)` method to "hide" the cursor and keep it inside your window. Just be aware that you need to call `Mouse.create()` once during setup, and `Mouse.destroy()` before exiting the game.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with LWJGL 3 as follows:

To hide the cursor but make it able to leave the window:

```
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN);
```

To keep it in the window as well, similar to LWJGL 2's grabbed mode:

```
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
```

To revert its state back to normal:

```
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL);
```