# Hide Java cursor at any place on the screen

Tags: java, swing, cursor

I wish to hide a cursor in a certain range of x and y positions. Here is some sample code that represents what I want to do.

```
if(x >= xLowerBound && x <= xUpperBound + 600 && y >= yLowerBound + 20 && y <= yUpperBound + 600)
    setCursor(blankCursor);
else
    setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
```

Now, I know that `setCursor()` can be applied to a certain object, and that is fine. However, that doesn't work for my purposes.

The only exception would be if I could somehow create a fullscreen invisible object in which I could use `setCursor` even though it's invisible like so:

```
JFrame hiddenWindow = new JFrame();
hiddenWindow.setMaximumSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
hiddenWindow.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

if(x >= xLowerBound && x <= xUpperBound && y >= yLowerBound && y <= yUpperBound)
    hiddenWindow.setCursor(blankCursor);
else
    hiddenWindow.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
```

(Note: This did not work.)

Just reiterating, I need to be able to use `setCursor()` anywhere on the screen, not just limited to one object unless I can create an invisible screen-sized object to use `setCursor()` in.

**Update 1:**

I suppose I could have been a little more clear with what I was doing. I have a main `JFrame` in the center of the screen. It does not take up the whole screen. I am setting the cursor to a blank cursor whenever it is in a certain distance away from the `JFrame` or inside the `JFrame` itself. However, I do not know how I would do that.

My idea was to perhaps use another `JFrame` that takes up the whole screen and is invisible behind it so that I can use `setCursor()` on that `JFrame`. for the space outside it. I hope this clarifies the question a bit more.

Comment: I doubt Java can control the cursor when it's outside one of its windows. So assuming you make the frame full screen, how will you click anything?

Comment: I added some more information. I hope that clarifies it some more.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Sorry about that. I got a bit busy. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MouseMotionListener` and override its `mouseMoved` method to check where the mouse is (in the components) and set the cursor type accordingly:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    Test() {
        final int x1 = 100, y1 = 100, x2 = 300, y2 = 300;

        BufferedImage cursorImg = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Cursor blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(cursorImg, new Point(0, 0), "blank cursor");
        Cursor defaultCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                if (x > x1 && x < x2 && y > y1 && y < y2)
                    setCursor(blankCursor);
                else
                    setCursor(defaultCursor);
            }
        });

        setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Test());
    }
}
```

Credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984117/1803551) for the trick of a blank cursor.

You cannot set the cursor outside of a Java window. You can go with your idea of an invisible, fullscreen, headless frame, but this is pretty dodgy and will also intercept all mouse events. Implementation will be the same.