# Java Swing - let mouse disappear

Tags: java, swing, mouse

I am writing a little Pong game using Java's Swing.

I would like to make the mouse disappear after a few seconds if it stands still above the `JPanel` I am drawing on, and reappear when it is moved.

Is there a way to do this in Java's Swing?

Comment: Try looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984071/how-to-hide-cursor-in-a-swing-application

Comment: You can find the solution for this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984071/how-to-hide-cursor-in-a-swing-application